# Data frame formatting. Rows and Columns

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I have the following data frame

```
      Sp1 Sp1 Sp1 Sp2 Sp2 Sp2 Sp3 Sp3 Sp3
count  1   0   3   5   2   0   2   4   1
plot   A   B   C   A   B   C   A   B   C
```

How do I transform the data frame to get something like this

```
      plot Sp1 Sp2 Sp3
        A   1   5   2   
        B   0   2   4
        C   3   0   1
```

Can someone help?

Comment: What's the origin of the input data.frame? Having duplicated column names is somewhat of an hint that the problem you are trying to solve should probably not exist in the first place, so perhaps there's an easier and more straightforward way to get to that desired result.  Also please consider including your data as a `dput()` output, i.e result of `dput(dataframe)`, especially when it seems more of a corner case (column names here are the confusing bit, not sure if a typo or not).

Comment: Desired output seems to be matrix of counts: `matrix(c(1,0,3,5,2,0,2,4,1), nrow = 3, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:3], paste0("Sp",1:3))) |> as.data.frame.matrix()` where input vector can be `unlist(df_["counts",1:9])`

Comment: The data frame is from several Excel sheets, and I want to combine them in a single dataframe with all the information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree with margusl you have this dataframe:

```
> df
  Sp1 Sp1 Sp1 Sp2 Sp2 Sp2 Sp3 Sp3 Sp3
count   1   0   3   5   2   0   2   4   1
plot    A   B   C   A   B   C   A   B   C
```

Convert to a matrix then give your rows and cols new names:

```
m<-matrix(data = df[1,], nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow = FALSE,
+        dimnames = NULL)
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "1"  "5"  "2" 
[2,] "0"  "2"  "4" 
[3,] "3"  "0"  "1" 
m<-as.data.frame(m)

colnames(m)<- unique(cols)
rownames(m)<- unique(r2)
> m
  Sp1 Sp2 Sp3
A   1   5   2
B   0   2   4
C   3   0   1
```

Is that what you wanted?